# Metabase + PostgresSQL on Docker - "Unauthenticated" error

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, metabase

Used `docker compose` for `metabase` and `postgres` images.

Managed to build successfully. Went through the Metabase setup, no hitches.

However, I can't seem to get past the sign in page. Each time I enter the correct username and password I used at the setup stage, it *still* returns me to the sign in page.

Checking the docker logs, I keep seeing this error on sign in attempts:

```
2022-09-24 23:24:31,502 DEBUG middleware.log :: GET /api/user/current 401 320.3 µs (0 DB calls)
"Unauthenticated"
```

Not sure what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer had nothing at all to do with Metabase or Docker, *but with my **Nginx** configuration*

Problem was in my `location` block. Initial settings were:

```
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:<some_port>;  # <- put correct port
  }
```

Changed them to

```
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;   # <- *changed to this*
      proxy_pass http://localhost:<some_port>;  # <- put correct port
      proxy_http_version 1.1;   # <- *add this*
  }
```

...and the error was gone: can log in now.